# Как вместить таблицу на всю высоту и получить размеры canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.width = "300px"; // изменяется
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.height = "100px"; // изменяется
let canvasWidth = 0; // как получить ширину canvas ?
let canvasHeight = 0; // как получить высоту canvas ?
console.log(canvasWidth);
console.log(canvasHeight);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 5px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
table tr:last-child td {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><canvas style="width:100%;height:100%"></canvas></td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: А вы уже учли, что style width = 100% только растягивает canvas, а не меняет реальные размеры? Т.е. координаты будут укладываться ровно на те размеры, что были у canvas по умолчанию.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME, согласен, просто пытаюсь его динамическим сделать без привязки к размерам, но для построения графика нужно будет постоянно генерировать новый размер при изменении ширины экрана. Почти вопрос уже решил.

Comment: @Sergey Mironov недавно пришлось делать адаптивный canvas, пришлось использовать событие resize и перерисовывать холст, вы на этом же пути?

Comment: @Александр, да, тоже пытаюсь через resize генерировать